# Test error message when validating model with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, error-handling

I've inherited a rails api and I'm trying to test controllers. I have an endpoint '/api/v1/vitcords' where I create new vitcords. The video model only has a validation name. So my doubt is how to test that when I create a new video without specify a name, I get the message error I want, that in this case is "Vitcord name has to be specified". Thanks.

This is the Vcord model

```
class Vcord
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Spacial::Document
  include Concerns::Vitcord::M3u8
  include Concerns::Vitcord::User

  # Validations
  validates_presence_of     :name

  # Atributes
  field :name,                type: String
  field :location,            type: Array, spacial: true
  field :address,             type: String
  field :closed,              type: Boolean, default: false
  field :public,              type: Boolean, default: false
  field :thumb,               type: String

end
```

This is the controller video_controller.rb

```
module Api::V1
  class VitcordsController < ApiController
    def create
      user = current_resource_owner

      # Validation
      param! :name, String, required: true
      param! :location, Hash, required: false
      param! :address, String, required: false

      ap params[:location]
      ap params[:location][:latitude]
      ap params[:location][:longitude]

      # Creating
      vcord = Vcord.new()
      vcord.name = params[:name] if params[:name]
      if params[:location] && params[:location]['latitude'] && params[:location]['longitude']
        vcord.location = {
          lng: params[:location]['longitude'],
          lat: params[:location]['latitude']
        }
      end
      vcord.address = params[:address] if params[:address]
      vcord.creator = user
      if vcord.save
        vcord.members.each do |member|
         Notification.generate_notification_for_vitcord_invited(vcord, member)
      end
      @vitcord = vcord
      else
        error(:internal_server_error, ["Vitcord name has to be specified"], nil)
      end
  end
end
```

And this is the spec

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "POST /api/v1/vitcords" do
  before(:each) do
    db_drop

    post "/oauth/token", {
     :grant_type => 'assertion', 
     :assertion => TOKEN
    }

    @token = response_json['access_token']
  end

  it "sends an error if a vitcord is created with name nil" do
    header 'Authorization', "Bearer #{@token}"
    post '/api/v1/vitcords', {  
      address: "Calle Rue del Percebe", 
      location: {
        latitude: 40.7127837,
        longitude: -74.00594130000002
      }
     }

     //This does not work but it would be something like this
     expect(error).to eq("Name has to be specified")
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should refactor your code, but answering your question, you can add an error to you object by doing (look that I used @vcord and not vcord):

```
@vcord.errors.add(:name, 'Vitcord name has to be specified')
```

(as you can see here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add)
and on your test:

```
expect(assigns(:vcord).errors.name).to eq('Vitcord name has to be specified').
```

Comment: Ok but where should I add the error message. In the model or in the controller?? I guess it should be in the model right??

Comment: This way I get two errors [ [0] "can't be blank", [1] "Vitcord name has to be specified"] Which would be the best way to configure that I just want to be the second one displayed. I don't need the name can't be blank